# Target parent element depending on class of child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm using the [bootstrap multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) library. I'm grouping options together and I want to style the group heading. The HTML ends up like:

```
<div id="status-dropdown">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label class="multiselect-group">Group 1</label>
        </li>
        <li class="customDropdownUL">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Option A"> Option A</label>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class="multiselect-group">Group 2</label>
        </li>
        <li class="customDropdownUL">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Option B">Option B</label>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="customDropdownUL">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="Option C"> Option C</label>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And my CSS is:

```
li{
    list-style-type: none;
}  

#status-dropdown li:has(> label.multiselect-group) {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 whitesmoke;
    padding-left: 10px; 
}
```

So if a `li` has a `label` with class of `multiselect-group` then give it a background and padding. However, this isn't working. See the jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/79hcv8kk/).

Note: I cannot simply put a class on the li as I would need to modify the library to do that.

How can I target a parent element depending on class of the child?

Comment: @Turnerj: That edit was vandalism and should **not** have been approved, let alone improved.

Comment: @BoltClock, ummm, I don't see where the vandalism was with that edit. It is cool if I'm wrong, can you explain what exactly was wrong? (maybe in chat)

Comment: @Turnerj: Code formatting for things that aren't code, like the words "library", "HTML", "class" and "child". The only code edits that were necessary and appropriate are the ones already in the question. Your changes were fine, however the other edit was not.

Comment: @BoltClock Ahhhh yep, I removed library and HTML from being code formatted but missed "class" and "child". In the future, reject and edit?

Comment: @Turnerj: Yep. IIRC, reject and edit takes you to the editor with the changes from the original edit completely removed, which gives you a clean slate to work with (on top of actually rejecting the edit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be attempting to use the `:has()` pseudo-class from [Selectors 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#relational). Although you are using it correctly, this feature hasn't yet been implemented, so it's not going to work anywhere.

There is no CSS-based alternative at the moment. Refer to [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) for updates and workarounds.

Comment: I feel like we should be excited for when this is supported, is this good direction for pseudo selectors to be going? Seems like a logical way to grab parent elements for specific child elements.